# SqlResultSetMapping with doube embedded key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a data model with class A and class B, both have more than one primary key. I try to put all the elements from A in a ResultSetMapping to be used in a query, but I think because A has a key that is entity(B), I get an exception.

```
class A {
   @Id 
   String id;

   @Id 
   String version;

   @Id
   B b;
}

class B{
   @Id
   String id;

   @Id
   String type;
}

@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "Mapping", entities = {
        @EntityResult(entityClass = A.class, fields = {
                @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "a_id"),
                @FieldResult(name = "version", column = "a_version"), 
                @FieldResult(name = "b.id", column = "a_b_id"),
                @FieldResult(name = "b.type", column = "a_b_type")
                }
```

I think because of B being a separate entity I get an error in the query:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null    at
>   java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.ArrayHelper.slice(ArrayHelper.java:131)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]

Answer (score 0):

First there are no @IdClass defined on A and B. They are used for example for EntityManager.find().

Second you must add @ManyToOne annotation to get that working

```
@Id
@ManyToOne
B b;
```